# How to specify fieldnames to label using DictReader?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am specifying fieldnames using `DictReader`, but not all of the columns are useful or even contain data.  How can I specify which columns to label?  Here is my code:

```
my_tot_reader = csv.DictReader(tot_file, delimiter=';', restkey='Empty Field')
            my_tot_reader.fieldnames = ("Date", 
                                        "Pivot ID", 
                                        "Empty Field", 
                                        "Empty Field", 
                                        "Empty Field", 
                                        "Empty Field", 
                                        "Empty Field", 
                                        "Status")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply re-use the same key for fields you want to ignore; you'll end up with one such entry in the row dictionary with one of the column values. You do have to provide enough fields to cover all columns up to the last you *do* want to include.

I'd provide the sequence as a keyword argument, and you could build the tuple through multiplication:

```
my_tot_reader = csv.DictReader(
    tot_file, delimiter=';', restkey='ignored',
    fieldnames=("Date", "Pivot ID") + ('ignored',) * 5 + ('status',))
```

I used the field name `'ignored'` instead.

Under the hood `dict(zip(fields, columns))` is used, which will only produce as many `(column, field)` combinations as there are matching columns and fields; if `fields` is shorter than the number of `columns` the remaining columns are ignored. Duplicate field names result in just one dictionary key surviving:

```
>>> columns = ('some_date', 'some_id', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'spam', 'eggs', 'some_status', 'qux', 'flub')
>>> fields = ("Date", "Pivot ID") + ('ignored',) * 5 + ('status',)
>>> dict(zip(fields, columns))
{'Date': 'some_date', 'Pivot ID': 'some_id', 'ignored': 'eggs', 'status': 'some_status'}
```

The extreneous columns are then assigned to the `restkey` key as a list. Simply not use the `'ignored'` key in the resulting rows, or delete it with `del row['ignored']` if you want to use the row dictionary elsewhere.